# Wagtail Pages from Django Model/AdminModel

Tags: django, wagtail

I can't seem to find any info on this, everything points to adding models to admin. I don't need that.

What I am trying to do is probably pretty simple. I have a django model AdminModel called Location. I have 23 locations plugged into the model. I would like a page for each location, with data from the model used to populate each page, and a listing page.

The locations make individual use of an inventory API and google places API. The keys are stored per location in the model, so if I can just get the pages stood up on my URL I have enough to populate them.

If it is possible, I would like to generate them as wagtail pages, so I can make use of some fields for content not stored in the model per location page. I'd be happy if I could just get the pages generated from the model data though.

I'll take a search term or a doc link. Like I said, my search terms are only finding AdminModel instructions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [RoutablePageMixin](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/routablepage.html).  You would create a single `LocationPage` model and include `RoutablePageMixin` in the definition of the model.  Pay particular attention to this part of the example on [this section of the page](http://How%20do%20you%20plan%20to%20navigate%20to%20each%20page?%20%20Do%20you%20plan%20to%20list%20them%20on%20an%20index%20page,%20or%20do%20you%20plan%20to%20include%20them%20in%20the%20nav?):

```
# Multiple routes!
@route(r'^year/(\d+)/$')
...
```

Note how `year` in this case is a parameter in the url.  That parameter could be your location ID which you would use to look up the `Location` before rendering the page.